# Boost filesystem complete replacement

Tags: c++, boost-filesystem

My old Boost code:

```
std::string CombinePath(const char* left, const char* right)
{
    boost::filesystem::path p =  boost::filesystem::complete( 
        boost::filesystem::path(right, boost::filesystem::native), 
        boost::filesystem::path(left, boost::filesystem::native) );

    return p.string();
}
```

In new Boost version this is compiled only with `#define BOOST_FILESYSTEM_VERSION 2`. What is `complete` replacement in the new Boost version?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/deprecated.html.

The replacement is `absolute`.